# JQuery : Remove class, not child content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to append the content into each `contentx` class like.

```
  <div id="sidebar">
     <div class="contentx"></div>
     <div class="contentx"></div>
   </div>
  <script>
    $("#sidebar .contentx").each(function()
    {
    //Append here
    }
 </script>
```

After Append I have, for example :

```
   <div id="sidebar">
     <div class="contentx">
       something 1 is inserted here.
     </div>
     <div class="contentx">
      something 2 is inserted here.
     </div>
   </div>
```

but I want to remove class="contentx" whenever the content is appended. This mean I have only :

```
<div id="sidebar">
 something 1 is inserted here.
 something 2 is inserted here.
</div>
```

How

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you just want to remove the class "contentX" from the div after the content has been added, you can try the following:

```
$('#sidebar .contextX').each(function () {
    // Append here.
}).removeClass('contextX');
```

EDIT: Seems I misread the question a little (based on your indicated desired output).

**Option 2**

If you want to remove the entire  element and replace it with the content of your choice? For that, you can try:

```
$('#sidebar .contextX').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith('<new content here.>');
});
```

[jQuery replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: It may remove only class. I want remove all div that have that class. For example. <div class='contextX contentY' id='mn'> <div>content</div> </div> . That means, after append and remove div, I just have only <div>content</div>. You understand my intention?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with replace

Answer (score 1):

Besides the append, call `removeClass`

```
 $("#sidebar .contentx").each(function()
{
//Append here
    $(this).removeClass('contentx');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var tmp = $(".contentx").html();    
$('.contentx').append(tmp);     
var tmp2 = $(".contentx").html();   
$('.contentx').remove();
$('#sidebar').append(tmp2);
```

Comment: Simple as $( "#sidebar .contextX" ).replaceWith(function() {
return $( this ).contents();
});